# postStop() method in case of actor fails

Tags: java, scala, akka

i was going through the topic Supervision in akka and i have a question

if i have an actor and i acquire some resources in preStart() method and release them in postStop() method . now due to some reason the actor goes down

My question is 
what will happen to the postStop() method?
will it get called or not?

if not then what will happen to the resources that i acquired?

please guide me what will happen if my actor is working individually and also if it is under supervision of some other actor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When the actor stopped or restarted, the `postStop()` is called in each case (suppose you haven't overridden `preRestart`, which calls `postStop` by default in case of a restart).
2. An actor is always under supervision, either

   - by its parent actor, or
   - by a [guardian](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html#The_Top-Level_Supervisors), if it's a top-level actor.